# Most recent and stable version of Oxygen Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I am using eclipse from several years but in latest versions I found various major bugs. Please help me in choosing stable version of Oxygen; I have checked with Oxygen M6 packages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't have a final stable release until June 2017. The current tested build in 4.7M6.

The current stable release of Eclipse is Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3).